# How to call a PL/SQL function returning an OracleRefCursor with Linq2DB?

Tags: c#, oracle, sys-refcursor, linq2db

I would like to call a PL/SQL function that returns a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

One of the ways I have tried looks like this:

```
var userIdParameter = DataParameter.Decimal("userId", user.Id);
var returnValue = new DataParameter { Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue };
var result = dataConnection.ExecuteProc("SECURITY.GetUserRoles", userIdParameter, returnValue);
```

This produces the following error:

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Are functions returning a `SYS_REFCURSOR` supported by [Linq2DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for such parameters was added in Linq2DB 1.8. You need to add `DataType = DataType.Cursor` to return parameter.

See example in linq2db tests: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/DataProvider/OracleTests.cs#L1881